# c# entity TableServiceContext.CreateQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, error-handling

I have this code :

```
                var existsQuery = from e
                     in TableServiceContext.CreateQuery<entity>(tableName)
                              where
                              e.PartitionKey == entity.PartitionKey
                              && e.RowKey == entity.RowKey
                              select e;
            entity existingObject;
            try
            {
                existingObject = existsQuery.First();
            }
            catch (Exception) { existingObject = null; }
```

I would just like to ask if it possible for me not to use try catch in times that the select statement didn't return any value, because without a try catch i throws an exception.

I'm doing an update or insert [image]
Image provided.

Comment: Is there any records returned by existsQuery?  Maybe switching to FirstOrDefault()? would work? Also is there an inner exception on the DataServiceQueryException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as below

```
var source = TableServiceContext.CreateQuery<entity>(tableName).Where(e=>e.PartitionKey == entity.PartitionKey  && e.RowKey == entity.RowKey);

if(source != null && source.Any())
{
    var existingObject = source.FirstOrDeFault();
    // do somthing with existingObject 
}else
{
    // existingObject is null 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First will fail if you return 0 records for your criteria, if you use FirstOrDefault you will return a null object (in most cases).

```
var existsQuery = from e
                 in TableServiceContext.CreateQuery<entity>(tableName)
                          where
                          e.PartitionKey == entity.PartitionKey
                          && e.RowKey == entity.RowKey
                          select e;
        entity existingObject = existsQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```